# Properly storing an 8 Byte Value in an assembly

Tags: c, assembly, hex, ascii

I have specific instructions to store the 8-byte hex value for "/bin/sh" in the %rax register.

So 8 Bytes would mean 64 bits.. so my first approach was to use the movq command.. but I can't determine how to properly format the command.

/bin/sh in hex is: 2f 62 69 6e 2f 73 68
which only takes 7 Bytes.. is there some sort of null terminator or padding I can have to properly write the command in?

```
  # Write the 8-byte hex value for "/bin/sh" to %rax register
  movq $0x68732f6e69622f, %rax
```

Eventually the command is going to be used by a syscall

Thanks!

Comment: Note that due to endianess, you need to flip the order of bytes.  Also, I wonder why you want to put these characters into a register; all system calls expect registers to contain pointers to strings.

Comment: I thought I did correctly in the code? Is there a need for a null terminator or anything to make it 8 bytes

Comment: Read the comment from @fuz, you probably misunderstood your "specific instructions". Unless this is an experimental syscall that you are implementing yourself...

Comment: Reading your post again, it seems that yes, you did indeed do it right!  Note that as is, the string is already NUL terminated.  You can do `movq $0x0068732f6e69622f, %rax` to explicitly highlight this fact.

Answer (score 0):

The register is a particular size, so it's taking 64 bits no matter what you do. It'll effectively zero-pad in the high-order bits. Moving `$0x1` in there is a single bit at the lowest value with the rest zeroes.

You don't "null terminate" these values, that'd have the effect of multiplying things by some arbitrary factor. `$0x1000` is not the same as `$0x0001` obviously.